# Ground offset when powering devices directly from 5VDC transformer

Tags: power, pi-zero-w, power-supply, pi-zero, measuring

I am reading in current sensor (ACS712 20A) values using the MCP3008 ADC into my rpi zero. I am also using a Songle SLA-05VDC-SL-C relay, and have found that both the current sensor being on, and especially the relay, when powered from the 5V rail on the pi, cause a reduction in the voltage of the 3V3 rail with respect to rpi ground.

To overcome this issue, I connected power to both devices from the rpi power supply directly. While this has worked, the ADC reading has an offset (systematic error) which it appears can be attributed, at least in part, to an offset of about 50mV between the rpi ground and the neutral terminal of the power supply.

My question is: can I and should I fix this simply by connecting the ground pin of the current sensor to the rpi ground line, while keeping the 5V pin connected to the live wire (coming from power source in parallel to the rpi). If not - why not?

Many thanks.

Comment: If you feed 5V through ANY gpio pin on your Raspberry you WILL need a new Raspberry. Now, go and look at voltage dividers and opto-isolators.

Comment: I am familiar with voltage dividers, I've had to use them to ensure that the voltage output of the current sensor does not exceed 3.3V in order to input it into the rpi. As for the recommendation to look into opto-isolators, thanks, sounds interesting, will look into those and if that applies here.